# Iphone SOAP call - parse schema

Tags: iphone, soap

I am perfectly able to call webservice and receive data. Problem is that i dont understand how can i parse schema received from soap call?

Thanyou for your anticipated help,
Regads,
Ain

Answer (score 0):

I use [SudzC](http://sudzc.com/), an open source Objective-C --> SOAP generator, to create a client-side proxy for calling SOAP web services.  Give it a try and you'll find that making SOAP calls is quite easy!

Answer (score 0):

I prefer [wsdl2objc](http://code.google.com/p/wsdl2objc/) but probably because I discovered it first and I use it extensively. I'll have to give SudzC a go one day too.

Takes all the stress out of SOAP.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a couple of tutorials on wsdl2objc, [here](http://brismith66.blogspot.com/search/label/iPhone%20Development)